# mod_rewrite, different get parameters, how distinguish

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry for asking maybe an obvious question but I have searched a lot and can't seem to get this to work.

Two examples of URLs I'm rewriting:

```
mydomain.com/search/searchword/
mydomain.com/index.php?page=search&sw=searchword
AND
mydomain.com/lists/12345/
mydomain.com/index.php?page=lists&id=12345
```

I can get one of them to work with:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&sw=$2
```

But if I add one more line it doesn't work for the second one:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&sw=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

Can I put some RewriteCond to say, if one parameter is id, do this, if it's sw, do that? Or how do you usually solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&sw=$2
```

The above code should work. What I did was move the `id` line to above the `sw` line and change what is in the second bracket from `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` to `([0-9]+)` because the `id` will only have numbers and not letters. So the first line will be executed (I'm not sure that's the correct term for it), if there is only numbers in the second folder then it will be an id, else it is a search term and use that one.

EDIT:

```
RewriteRule ^lists/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&sw=$2
```

Comment: This does work. But I'm wondering if this is the correct way of doing this? Because what if both were in letters... What then? Thank you.

Comment: As I do have these kind of url's with more than one of each, I'm happy for answers beyond this too. Are there no RewriteCond for this? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer, the id can now contain letters or numbers. As for your second comment. I am by far not an expert, so asking another question (and/or researching/googling a bit) might yield an answer for that.